# Struts2 JQuery grid JSON result hijacking

Tags: json, struts2, struts2-json-plugin, struts2-jquery-grid

I am using struts2 jquery grid in my current project.The `dataType` used in jquery grid is `json`. Everything works like charm. There was a security audit of my application and they pinpointed the **JSON Hijacking vulnerability**. I searched the internet for mitigating the json hijacking in general & solution in struts2. I quite fing good documentation.
  [Json Hijacking](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/)

[Prevent Struts2 from JSON Hijacking](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON+Plugin)

I used the prefix param set to true in json result type in struts.xml. All is working fine , i got the json data prefixed with {}&&. As described in **Link 2** this is used to mitigate the json hijacking.

The problem i faced is that jQuery Grid is not able to load Data.

My struts.xml

```
<action name="myjson" class="action.JsonTable">
<result type="json">
<param name="prefix">true</param>
</result>
```

The grid is not able to populate.Wen i remove `<param name="prefix">true</param>` from the action defnition, everything works fine. But it is vulnerable :(

Comment: The plugin loads it just fine, you need to post the code that shows the error you made.

Comment: @Roman There is no error.The grid does not get populated when i use prefix param in json result type.